# Trouble finding a way to simulate a player moving in React game

Tags: reactjs

I am building a simple game using react that involves a 3x3 grid of buttons. The player is represented by the middle button. The other buttons are populated by items (chests, energy, etc.) that are randomly generated from a weighted loot table function.

The player can "move" to any of the surrounding buttons by clicking on them, in which case I will need the *clicked* button to become the player, keep the existing loot table rolls and add new ones based on the direction the player "moved" in. I am having a really difficult time figuring this out (in terms of even where to start) and would love any input or guidance :)

```
import LootTable from "./LootTable";

var loot = new LootTable();
loot.add("chest", 1);
loot.add("energy", 1);
loot.add("roll", 1);
loot.add("empty", 5);

//create square
const Square = (props) => {
  return <button className="square">{props.value}</button>;
};

//create board with 9 squares
const Board = () => {
  const renderSquare = (i) => {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {renderSquare(loot.choose())}
          {renderSquare(loot.choose())}
          {renderSquare(loot.choose())}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {renderSquare(loot.choose())}
          {renderSquare("player")}
          {renderSquare(loot.choose())}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {renderSquare(loot.choose())}
          {renderSquare(loot.choose())}
          {renderSquare(loot.choose())}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

I tried creating a variable to temporarily store the results of the rolls and refresh only the "new" buttons but I could not figure out a way to accomplish both tasks. Either all of the buttons re-roll or none of them do

Comment: Don't you need some state to keep track of where the player is?

Comment: the player technically never moves, the board just moves around the player

Comment: Same difference: without some state to keep track of what's changing, you're going to be hard-pressed to implement movement regardless of how the movement is done.